# How to replace char in file with appropriate ascii code in vim…

Tags: vim

In a vim buffer if I have a list of characters say:

A

B

c

C

d

D

and for each one I want to replace it with its corresponding ascii code ( in decimal ).  Is there a way to do this without using an external tool through :r!some_tool

For instance, I know there is the :ascii and ga commands but they print the value to the screen but I can't find a way to get its output into the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [str2numchar.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1646).  Down load & install in your vim plugins folder.  Add the example visual mode key map to your .vimrc file:

```
vmap <silent> sn :Str2NumChar<CR>
```

In vim, highlight the text you want to convert and type `sn`.

Comment: Very close to what I want... And I could it could work for me with a little of extra search and replace afterwards.  However, I think I like the answer posted on stackoverflow more because it doesn't use a plugin and is pretty much everything I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834114/how-to-replace-char-in-file-with-appropriate-ascii-code-in-vim
Thanks for the advice though...

Comment: I do like the visual nature of this solution though...

Comment: No worries.  If you can remember how to invoke that funtion inside a search clause like that, then you're my hero ;-)